# Creating video from images with FFmpeg4Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using this http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html for implementing what I need.

My code for Creating video from images is:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 60; i++) 
{
 commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i /sdcard/TApp/Media/"+i+".jpg /sdcard/TApp/Media/out.mp4";            
 setCommand(commandStr);
 runTranscoing();

}
```

And I`m not getting the right result. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have coded wrongly. You just have to specify the `Image Series` for making Video from images. That means all the images should have a name in series. Take a look at [Ffmpeg Doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) for a better understanding.

Also you have not specified the filter to be used for encoding the video.
Make a change like this to code

```
String cmnd ="ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4";
setCommand(cmnd);
runTranscoing();
```

Cheers. :)